# Now that c# is the only language supported by Unity, do we need to tag Unity questions with c#?

Tags: discussion, tags

It's been around for a while: [Boo](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/09/03/documentation-unity-scripting-languages-and-you/) and [UnityScript](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/08/11/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset/) have been removed from Unity.

Now, the obvious is that issues with Unity will be tackled in `c#`. Also, the new Unity users may even not be aware that there was something other than `c#` in the past.

Given the fact that the system seems to properly highlight `c#` code even without the [c#](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag, is there still a need to tag the questions that are tagged with [unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity) with [c#](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23) too?

If not, do we need to do an edit *just to remove the tag* or should it be done if there is something else to edit, or do we care at all?

---

Of course, I'm not talking about questions that are specific about `c#` within the context of Unity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd follow this rule:

- If the question contains C# code, tag it C#
- If the question lacks code, but asks about scripting a feature in (a recent or unspecified version of) Unity, tag it C#
- If the question asks about solving non-scripting problems in Unity (eg  scene setup, asset management), do not tag it C#

In the first two points, even if the C# language can be inferred without the tag, I think it's beneficial to include for two reasons:

- Many Unity scripting questions do not require Unity-specific expertise to solve, so anyone following the C# tag may have relevant experience to offer in answers/edits/comments/votes/flags
- Many C# game programming questions come up in the context of Unity, so it's useful if a user searching for C# Q&A also finds Unity C# results included